# Returning minimum of array with for loop iteration

Tags: python

I received this line of code that I'm having trouble understanding syntactically.

```
def coinsNeeded(coins, price, mincoinList):
     return min([mincoinList[price-coin] for coin in coins if coin <= price]) + 1
```

What I know so far is that `coins` and `mincoinList` are both arrays of integers and that `price` is also an integer.

From my understanding, the `min()` function requires an iterable or two arguments, so I don't quite understand what values are being compared in the `min()` function.

Comment: the `min` function requires an `iterable` and returns the minimum of all the elements in it.

Comment: Right but exactly what is the relationship between the array[price-coin] and the for loop?

Comment: min does not need two iterables, you are getting the min value of a single list

Comment: How would I break this up into multiple lines in order to read it more clearly though? `mincoinsList[price-coin]` is using the variable `coin` which appears in the for loop `for coin in coins` so how is this for loop related to `mincoinsList` syntactically or exactly how is this minimum being calculated?

Comment: It's getting the minimum of the subset of mincoinList where coin <= price (otherwise it would be trying to access a negative array index).  Read up more on list comprehensions if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min([mincoinList[price-coin] for coin in coins if coin <= price]) + 1
```

Let’s disect this line!

The core part of this is the following list comprehension:

```
[mincoinList[price-coin] for coin in coins if coin <= price]
```

List comprehensions are a way to create a list by looping over some sequence. In this case, we are creating a list with elements of the value `mincoinList[price - coin]` for each `coin` in the `coins` list **if** the value of `coin` is lower or equal to `price`.

So in other words, it selects those coins which are lower than the price, and then for each of those, it gets an element from `mincoinList` with the difference of the price and coin as the index.

Finally, that list is passed to [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) which just returns the element from the list with the lowest value. That value is then incremented by one and returned from the function.

---

You could write this all in a very verbose multi-line code like this:

```
selectedCoins = []
for coin in coins:
    if coin <= price:
        selectedCoins.append(mincoinList[price - coin])

return min(selectedCoins) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
def coinsNeeded(coins, price, mincoinList):
     return min([mincoinList[price-coin] for coin in coins if coin <= price]) + 1
```

has a list comprehension which is equivalent to:

```
def coinsNeeded(coins, price, mincoinList):
     minCoinNeeded = []
     for coin in coins:
         if coin <= price:
             minCoinNeeded += mincoinList[price-coin]
     return min(minCoinNeeded) + 1
```